SQL query within the same table
I'm use to simple SQL queries and can't get this one.
I have a members table that is set like so:
member_id | member_number | member_fname | member_name | member_parent_id | member_status
member_parent_id is a reference to member_id

I need to get all the members where the member_parent_id is not null
Get the member_number as an extra column for the parent for each members

So far I got results but can't figure how to add the extra column for the parent member_number
SELECT members.member_id, member_id_parent, member_nbr, member_fname, member_name, member_note
    FROM members
    LEFT JOIN .... other table
    LEFT JOIN .... other table
    WHERE member_id_parent IS NOT NULL
    AND member_status = 1
;

I have tried some example with WITH RECURSIVE but could figure out the logic and do the proper corrections to make it work.
Thanks,

Please read [mre] and then edit your question with example data and desired results, as per Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

The table has  member_parent_id  but your query has  member_id_parent is there a typo somewhere?

Yes  P.Salmon this is a typo. should be member_parent_id Thanks for caching this.

does the answers provide solve your problem @MarcDG  ?

@DerekRoberts  Both solutions work, but  I prefer the first one because it resemble more what I am use to.  Since this is just to extract data for a migration, I am not looking for something performing, should the other one be. Many thanks for yours !

Hey @MarcDG awesome! No worries , the most important thing is that it works and you solved your problem . ;) always happy to help.

Use name aliases for the table. Here I use m for the member and p for the parent:
SELECT m.member_id, m.member_id_parent, m.member_nbr, 
       m.member_fname, m.member_name, m.member_note,
       p.member_fname as parent_fname,
       p.member_name  as parent_name,
       p.member_note  as parent_note
    FROM members m
    LEFT JOIN members p ON p.member_id = m.member_id_parent
    LEFT JOIN .... other table
    LEFT JOIN .... other table
    WHERE m.member_id_parent IS NOT NULL
    AND m.member_status = 1
;


Yup! This works .

Here are the steps you can use to solve this.

You can create a CTE to get each member_id and member_number for all members in your table.

The next step is to use the created CTE to join with the query used to fetch the parent_member_number.


Here is a quick demo on fiddble
WITH ParentMembers AS (
    SELECT 
        member_id, 
        member_number AS parent_member_number
    FROM 
        members
)
SELECT 
    m.member_id, 
    m.member_parent_id, 
    m.member_number, 
    m.member_fname, 
    m.member_name, 
    p.parent_member_number -- another other parent member_number
FROM 
    members m
LEFT JOIN 
    ParentMembers p ON m.member_parent_id = p.member_id
WHERE 
    m.member_parent_id IS NOT NULL
    AND m.member_status = 1;



Thanks for the Fiddle! This one also does the work !

I am curious to understand. So the WITH creates a temp table that you can use with a simple JOIN ? I will keep this one in my librairy. I see some good uses.

@MarcDG well yeah it is always a good thing to have in your toolkit haha! glad it helped. ;)
